# Not able to update state while using redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit

I am trying to create a user authentication flow using `react router dom v6` and and `redux toolkit`. But sometimes it seems the state is not updating in redux.

Here is how I have created my authentication slice.

> AuthenticationSlice

```js
const initialState = {
  isAuthenticating: false,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isAuthenticationError: false,
  error: null,
};

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    loggingInUser: (state) => {
      state.isAuthenticating = true;
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
    },
    loggedInUser: (state, payload) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = true;
      state.isAuthenticating = false;
    },
    loggingUserFail: (state, payload) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.isAuthenticating = false;
      state.error = payload.error;
    },
    logoutUser: (state, payload) => {
      state.isAuthenticated = false;
      state.isAuthenticating = false;
      state.isAuthenticationError = false;
    },
  },
});

export const authSelector = (state) => state.auth;

export const {
  
  loggedInUser,
  loggingInUser,
  loggingUserFail,
  
  logoutUser,
} = authSlice.actions;

export default authSlice.reducer;

export function loginUserThunk(body) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(loggingInUser());
    try {
      const response = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: `${BASE_URL}/auth/login`,
        data: body,
      });
      if (response.data.data) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          "access_token",
          response?.data?.data?.access_token
        );
        setAuthorizationHeader(response.data.data);
        dispatch(loggedInUser(response.data.data));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(loggingUserFail(error));
    }
  };
}
```

> Login.js

```js
import { loginUserThunk } from "../../redux/slices/auth";

function Login() {
  const dispath = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, errors, touched, values } =
    useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        username: "",
        password: "",
      },
      onSubmit: (values) => {
        dispath(loginUserThunk(values));
        navigate("/");
      },
    });
  return (
    <Container>
      <Grid
        container
        justifyContent={"center"}
        display={"flex"}
        alignItems={"center"}
        height={"100vh"}
        width={"100%"}
      >
        <Grid item>
          <Card sx={{ minWidth: 500 }}>
            <Box p={2}>
              <Typography variant="h5">Login to explore</Typography>
            </Box>
            <CardContent>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Stack>
                  <TextField
                    name="username"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.username}
                    sx={{ marginTop: 2 }}
                    placeholder="UserName"
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                  <TextField
                    name="password"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    value={values.password}
                    sx={{ marginY: 2 }}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    type={"password"}
                    variant="outlined"
                  />
                  <Button type="submit" variant="contained">
                    Login
                  </Button>
                  <Box marginTop={2}>
                    <Typography>
                      New User ? <Link to={"/register"}>Register</Link>
                    </Typography>
                  </Box>
                </Stack>
              </form>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Here even after dispatching `dispatch(loggedInUser(response.data.data));` loggedInUser `isAuthenticated` state is not updating.

Comment: Do you see `loggedInUser` being dispatched in the redux devtools? If so, does it change the state at all? I don't see any obvious issues in your code snippets. Although I'm wondering why you're calling `navigate("/")` right after the dispatch. Shouldn't you wait for the login to be successful? (transition from false to true for `isAuthenticated `).

Comment: This is always been a confusing part to me can you please explain to me how to add promise after dispatching events. @timotgl

Comment: You're not meant to wait for a call like `dispatch(loginUserThunk(values));` to finish. This scenario can however be solved in two ways: 1) move `navigate("/")` into `loginUserThunk` (because there you have precise control over the async flow) or 2) get `isAuthenticated` via `useSelector` and use a `useEffect` hook to call `navigate("/")` when the flag is true.